# Given a constant thrust to weight ratio, how to calculate the quickest path between two points on earth?

Tags: rockets, trajectory

I'm trying to understand what would shortest paths could looks like.

Let's assume a few things

1. We have a constant thrust to weight ratio
2. We do not need to decelerate
3. We need to take drag into account
4. No wind/surface terrain

How to calculate the quickest path between two points on earth ?

I suspect the third point might be a bit complicated so some simplification can be made

Comment: Does your vehicle have a constant acceleration throughout? (Apart from the effects of drag that is.) I see this question as a short climb above the atmosphere then a long powered phase keeping the apogee as low as practical, then entering the atmosphere at the end of the flight. That would be faster than a normal ballistic trajectory I think...

Comment: @andy nope. With constant acceleration the fastest path would be the shortest one since fuel is out of the equation

Comment: But the shortest one would be through the atmosphere, wouldn't it? That could be quite slow.  A ballistic (ICBM style) high arc would be quite quick, but with *constant* thrust I think you want to follow the Earth's curvature just above the atmosphere (possibly thrusting downwards to prevent going into an escape path) before dipping into atmosphere again. (Did I understand the question correctly?)

Comment: Agreed the fastest path (provided the distance is long enough) will be out of the atmosphere first since drag will decrease acceleration with constant thrust to weight

Comment: Most rockets go up and back down on a curve. The cruise missile would travel in a strait line like a plane. So the cruise missile travels the shortest path but intercontinental rockets go faster and cost more.

Comment: (Yes you understood correctly)

Comment: This is Calculus of Variations problem, in particular, a variation on the geodesic problem with a somewhat more complicated functional (transit time based on the aforementioned assumptions rather than just arc length).